# How to use rectangle selector on matplotlib figure with double y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, position, axis

I built a tkinter graphic interface for data manipulation with matplotlib and I need to use the rectangle selector from matplotlib.widgets to be able to select specific data (this works fine):

```
# Create rectangle selector

self.toggle_selection_var=tk.IntVar(value = 1)
self.selection_coords=[]
def toggle_selector():
    if self.toggle_selection_var.get() == 1 and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)
    elif self.toggle_selection_var.get() == 0 and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
def onselect(eclick, erelease):                           #this is here because used by rectangleselector below
    self.selection_coords=[eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata, erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata]
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(self.ax, onselect,
                                        useblit=True, 
                                        button=[1, 3],          # disable middle button
                                        minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                        spancoords='pixels',
                                        interactive=True,
                                        drag_from_anywhere=True,
                                        use_data_coordinates=True)
```

Recently I updated my tkinter GUI to be able to show a secondary axis using :

```
self.ax2 = self.ax.twinx()
```

but by doing so the rectangle selector (that works on primary ax) became invisible.

I think it is a matter of ax position because I tried to modify the primary ax z position using:

```
self.ax.set_zorder(self.ax2.get_zorder() + 1)
```

And then the rectangle selector could be seen again BUT all the plots on ax are invisible now and I can only see plots made on ax2.

So here is my question: is there a way to have 2 y axis on matplotlib AND still be able to use rectangle selector on the first ax ?

PS: don't mind all the "self.", I just put all the matplotlib objects as class variables so I can manipulate them from anywhere in my code

Comment: See [Matplotlib pick event with multiple axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739453/matplotlib-pick-event-with-multiple-axes)

Answer (score 1):

Ok the solution is simply to set the background of ax to transparent using this:

```
ax.set_facecolor("none")
```